# How to check if a text file only contains certain characters (eg. 's','f','#','\n')(update)

Tags: c++

I am doing a maze program and read the maze from a file, but i need to check the file only contain "s","f"，“#” or "\n" characters otherwise print error messages? i tried many times , but really confused it ~
Now i'm trying to use STL to solve it, but have new problems!

```
    void fillList(list<char> &myList, const char *mazeFile )
    {
         ifstream inFile;
         string lines;
         inFile.open(mazeFile);
         while(!inFile.eof())
         {
             getline(inFile,lines);
             for(int i=0;i<lines.length();i++)
                 myList.push_back(lines[i]);
         }
    }   
    bool checkMaze(list<char> &myList)
    {
         list<char>::iterator itr;
         for (itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++ )
         {
             if(*itr != 's' || *itr != 'f' || *itr != '#' || *itr != '\n')
                 return false;
         }
         return true;
    }


myMaze.fillList(myList,argv[1]);
bool valid = myMaze.checkMaze(myList);
if(myMaze.isValid(argv[1]) && valid == true)
    myMaze.printMaze();
else
{
    cout << "Unable to load maze " << argv[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But it still not print ? what problem with that ?

Comment: You need to post some code to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I think you might need the space character too, or the maze will be all walls.

Comment: i used the method showed below , but i found that it for string but not for character ! the above code i used iterator ~ but not sure what's wrong with it !

Comment: Where did you learn to write `while(!inFile.eof())`? It's wrong.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbi, from book !our lecture ~ but the problem without the checkMaze() function it works ! what i want to to is try to compare each character of the file with these three characters if none of them , then return false, otherwise return true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a std::string, you might consider the various string search member functions.

E.g. [string::find_first_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/)

```
  std::string str ("s###X##f");
  std::size_t found = str.find_first_not_of("sf#\n");
  if (found!=std::string::npos)  {
     std::cout << "The first non-acceptible character is " << str[found];
     std::cout << " at position " << found << '\n';
  }
```

Comment: This is a very generic answer. Please provide correct solution not hint.

Comment: @Nilesh: In all fairness, this is a really big hint even without the link.  But yeah, the answer would be better with an example.

Comment: Hey, okay, @Nilesh, Erwin and cHao, I'll add an example, for posterity.  I'm sympathetic to the argument that the link could break (even though that particular site has been very stable and the name of that standard library function itself can be looked up in compiler-specific documentation).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that checks if a file contains a specific string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool wordExists(char* file, char* word)
{
    string line;
    ifstream fileStream;
    fileStream.open(file);

    //until we can't read any more lines 
    while( getline(fileStream, line) )
    {
        if ( line.find(word) != string::npos )
            return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since you haven't provided your implementation of the problem, I can't determine what your error was - but feel free to let me know if this code doesn't work (I just roughed it out in Notepad++ for this question) or if you have any additional concerns.

Comment: yeh i know it ! but i mean the file should only only contain a specific string. i did the same solution as you !

Comment: such as a file if only contain "s","f"，“#” or "\n" characters then i print it otherwise print out a error message said “invalid characters”

Comment: @user3567012 Okay, then check for each word in the while loop, and in the case that none of the strings are found, return false. Pass in multiple strings as parameters.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it ! but another question is if i found them but also found other character like "%"? then how to do